# Redirect blog url with permalink change using redirection plugin

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I am trying to redirect everything on the my website. The currently site uses **[www.abc15421.com/year/month/date/abc-post](http://www.abc15421.com/year/month/date/abc-post)** in the URL. i want to remove year/month/date from url and url looks like **[www.abc15421.com/abc-post](http://www.abc15421.com/abc-post)**
I want to change permalink but if changed that then previous blog url not working so anyone have idea then help me
I am using redirection plugin but not getting proper way to resolved this. If anyone have idea then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) if you want to use Wordpress plugins, and follow [those instructions](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/wordpress-redirects-permalinks/) to make things work